# Handling undefined Values with Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple form in my web application that persists a JSON object to my Firebase database. Not every field on this form is required, so when the object being sent is constructed, it may have several `undefined` properties.

Being that Firebase throws an error when trying to persist `undefined` values, (not to mention, you should not have an `undefined` value on a JSON object), I'm wondering if there's any method provided by the framework to override all undefined values to `null` or even an empty string; I've yet to find a solution online.

Worst case scenario I could set all undefined properties to `null` manually but I'd rather not do that

Any ideas or suggestions on this?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 35):

For those using Firestore, it's now possible to ignore `undefined` fields: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1031#issuecomment-636308604

> **elmasry:** As of today May 29, 2020, Firebase Added support for calling FirebaseFiresore.settings with { ignoreUndefinedProperties: true }. When this parameter is set, Cloud Firestore ignores undefined properties inside objects rather than rejecting the API call.

Example:

```js
firebase.firestore().settings({
  ignoreUndefinedProperties: true,
})

await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('products')
  .doc(productId)
  .update({
    name: undefined, // Won't throw an error
  })
```

Answer (score 11):

My solution was to simply `stringify()` the object combined with a `replacer` to replace all undefined values

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, function(k, v) {
   if (v === undefined) { return null; } return v; 
}));
```

Then I convert it back to an object with JSON `parse()`

Comment: A little updated syntax:  obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v)  => v === undefined ? null : v))

Answer (score 6):

As of the breaking changes in Firebase 9 JS SDK it can be written like this:

```js
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {
  initializeFirestore,
} from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

export const FirebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'example',
  authDomain: 'example.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'example',
  storageBucket: 'example.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'example',
  appId: 'example',
  measurementId: 'example',
};

const app = initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);

initializeFirestore(app, {
  ignoreUndefinedProperties: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are any particular methods for this due to the nature of JSON expecting a value to be passed in, which in this case could be 'null' or an empty string.

As unfortunate as this may be at the moment, I would think it would be better to handle this at the client end and manually add 'null' or an empty string if no data is entered. You can then later test data at that location in Firebase using something like '*snapshot.val() !== null*'.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Can a value be `undefined||null`? `fbRef.set(JSON.stringify(obj))`/`fbRef.once(snap=>{const obj=JSON.parse(snap.val())})`, otherwise as usual.

To store a JSON object with undefined/unknown values, stringify it and store it to Firebase, then parse to recover it. This will avoid undesired/ unforeseen sets/update errors.

If the object is part of your firebase paths, then proceed with Kurai's solution. Be aware that Firebase will not store a key with `null` or `undefined` as value, then if you want to update it later, it will fail. If you want the path to remain after changes or to maintain such keys, set them to `0` (Be aware of the side-effects).

Comment: Wow thanks this really saved me a lot.
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` before set or push to database.
It would simply remove all the undefined object keys.
Thanks David

Answer (score 1):

For someone searching for generic solution to clean out null & undefined values this might help.

create a helper function like this and wrap the object you want to clean.

```
const Obj = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: null, // Warning: null values would be preserved
  key3: undefined
}

function cleanObj(object) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))
}

const test = cleanObj(Obj)
console.log(test)
```